# pyparsing: using character depending on condition

Tags: python, pyparsing

So the character I got two uses for is the double colon '**:**'.

I'm using pyparsing to parse strings containing alphanums (numbers and letters) and IP4/IPV6 addresses.
The grammar looks like the following:

```
term = Word(alphanums + '.' + ':')
```

And following that I use a parseAction function on `term`.
The thing is now, that I also use infixNotation as a BooleanParser for `term` and the operator for OR is also the double colon (can't use something else btw).

```
exp = infixNotation(term,
            [
            (NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, Not_func),
            (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, And_func),
            (':', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, Or_func),
            ])
```

I need the program now to check beforehand if the term is an IPV6 address or not and if it is, the double colon shouldn't be seen as the operator for OR, but as part of the term.

I was thinking of maybe using a different grammar for IPV6 adresses, but then again I need the boolean parser for those too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it help if you use the IPV6 expression defined in `pyparsing_common`? Also, your expression for `term` is pretty ambiguous. Is "....." a valid term? or ".3.32:::...X"? Try making this more specific like `term = pyparsing_common.ipv4_address | pyparsing_common.ipv6_address | pyparsing_common.number | Word(alphas + "_", alphanums + "_") | quotedString`.  I think then you will not have any ambiguity with your infix ':' operator. Also see this page of the pyparsing wiki: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki/Common-Pitfalls-When-Writing-Parsers

Comment: @PaulMcG Thank you so much! I did see that pyparsing_common has expression for ipv6 and ipv4, but didnt understand how they work. Finally got it to work now and the link u gave me is also very helpful, thanks again! :)